# Perform keypress on audio cue. Is this a simple program?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my first post and I am very new to Python so please excuse if I ask something a little daft.

I am thinking about trying to make a simple script that can complete a keypress upon hearing a certain audio cue. Is this an easy task or is this something that requires advanced knowledge?

Much appreciate any input.

Many thanks,
Phil

Comment: So your program would listen to the microphone and do something when it recognizes some particular audio? That's certainly not trivial. (Simulating a keypress isn't hard, though.) What's your actual use case here?

Comment: Hi and thanks for the response. The situation would be like playing a video game and upon ingame audio giving a particular ding/audio cue then the keybind would be pressed. So sorry for not being clear at the start, but the audio is coming from ingame/application. Thanks

Comment: I assume you mean a second app (game) that plays the sound? It would still require recognizing the particular audio cue, which is not trivial at all. Can you tell us what you're actually trying to do, in concrete terms? E.g. "When Overwatch plays McCree's "It's High Noon", I want my app to automatically send a keypress"?

Comment: Gotcha, sounds like it wouldn't be a task for a beginner then! Basically thinking of a project to get myself learning and this idea was involving making a fishing bot. 1 button press to cast a line, wait for the audio cue that tells us a fish is hooked and then automatically press a 2nd button. Hope this makes more sense. Thanks again AKX

Comment: If the game's graphics are fairly simple, it would be easier to implement this by scanning the graphical output (where it's easy to "look at" the color values of pixels). :)

Comment: Ah yes, I have heard about similar techniques, but for some reason I thought it might have been easier going via the audio route. Is the solution you are suggesting difficult? Do you know of any good learning materials that might guide me on the path you mentioned above? Much appreciated

Comment: The PyAutoGUI library can both take screenshots and emulate key/mouse actions. https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html